# How to fix Contact Form 7 issue with JSON and trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, contact-form-7

I'm struggling with such type of error while trying to fix CF7 issue with not sending messages:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

I've found at WP support forums that it's because of some .htaccess rules rewrite such kind of URLs with trailing slashes:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1253/feedback
```

I have a very complex .htaccess and not able to fix it myself.

But can be some rule added to it to fix the issue - remove trailing slash for all URLs starting with 
/wp-json/?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Force trailing slash in WP without damaging the admin interface or the JSON API
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/wp-json
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/wp-admin
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)([^./])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Check here [Add trailing slashes in WordPress Multisite without damaging the admin interface or the JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536401/add-trailing-slashes-in-wordpress-multisite-without-damaging-the-admin-interface)